# UISplitViewController how to show the master view?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I need a ridiculously simple thing - in one of the detail views of my `UISplitViewController` I have a button. Clicking it should show/open master view. That's it. Is it even possible?

**P.S.** it should work for all the layouts (iphone & ipad) and orientations. Even if the detail view part is a navigation and I am deep inside several pages, just want to open master view. You can assume iOS8+.

---

**EDIT:** Just to clarify what I meant by "deep inside several pages". Here is my storyboard screenshot:
[image]

Suppose I have a button in **Detail Page 2** which should show the master. Setting the `preferredDisplayMode` works only for non-compact sizes, like iPad. On iPhone 6, for example, nothing changes after setting it. The back button points on **Detail Page 1** so even swiping doesn't open master, it goes to previous page in detail navigation. I noticed that in this mode there is no split view at all, it is simulated by a navigation controller. So the questions is: is what I need possible at all or am I wrong trying to conceptually treat it as a "left drawer" which can be opened in any case and device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At iOS8+ you can change visibility of the master view using
an animatable property `preferredDisplayMode`

```
@property (nonatomic) UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode preferredDisplayMode
```

Universal way to change visibility for all iOS versions is overriding delegate method

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return _needsHideMasterView;
}
```

Here `_needsHideMasterView` is BOOL ivar which can be changed in your code to hide master view. For example,

```
- (void)hideMasterView:(BOOL)needsHide
{
    _needsHideMasterView = needsHide;

    [splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    [splitViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, both are not working in case of compact sizes (like iPhone6 portrait) and being deep in detail navigation. I will now update the question with my storyboard screenshot to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

try setting preferredDisplayMode to UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible like

```
    self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
```